# VLAN trunk port not working with ESXi 5

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vlan, pfsense

I just purchased my first VLAN-capable switch (SLM2008T-NA), and I tried to configure my first vlan on it. However, I am not able to make my trunk port work with ESXi 5.

Here is my current setup:

```
Port 8 -> Access, PVID 300, Admit Untagged Only
...
Port 1 -> Trunk, PVID 300, (I guess it's obviously tagged, since it's a trunk port ?)
```

Basically, port 8 is my LAN, and port 1 is connected to a vSwitch in ESXi, which is connected to a pfSense appliance.

I am not able to make my trunk port communicate with ESXi, it does not work whether by specifiying VLAN ID 300 in my port group in ESXi, or even by adding a VLAN interface under pfSense (with no VLAN specified in ESXi).

Also, Ingress Filtering is enabled on all ports, I don't know if this option could change something.

I'm a bit confused here, it's the first time I am working with VLANs, am I doing something wrong ?

Also, as a side question, is it a better idea to let ESXi handle VLANs, or adding a VLAN interface in pfSense and let it manage this ?

Answer (score 2):

It is most certainly better to let ESXi handle the VLANs. I suspect your problem is that you specified a PVID on the trunk port. You should be setting an allowed VLAN, not setting the native one. Try setting the PVID to 0 or 1, and then allowing VLAN300 on the port.